Is it expected behavior for Linux to NOT do subsequent DNS requests to resolve to an IP?
My machine is Debian 12. Here is the result of nslookup
lhtadmin@deb12-docker1:~$ nslookup nc.domain.com
Server:172.16.100.4
Address:172.16.100.4#53

nc.domain.com canonical name = lb2.local.domain.com.
lb2.local.domain.com canonical name = deb12-docker2.local.domain.com.

When I tried to do curl nc.domain.com, I got the message "could not resolve". Here is the log from my DNS server (Pihole). Also, My Pihole is setup to forward zone .local.domain.com to 192.168.1.1
Oct 16 14:08:25: query[A] nc.domain.com from 172.16.100.20
Oct 16 14:08:25: config nc.domain.com is <CNAME>
Oct 16 14:08:25: config lb2.local.domain.com is <CNAME>

However, if I try the same curl command on a macOS, it will do another lookup for deb12-docker2.local.domain.com to resolve to an IP
Oct 16 14:03:33: query[A] nc.domain.com from 172.16.110.251
Oct 16 14:03:33: config nc.domain.com is <CNAME>
Oct 16 14:03:33: config lb2.local.domain.com is <CNAME>
Oct 16 14:03:33: query[A] deb12-docker2.local.domain.com from 172.16.110.251
Oct 16 14:03:33: forwarded deb12-docker2.local.domain.com to 192.168.1.1
Oct 16 14:03:33: reply deb12-docker2.local.domain.com is 172.16.100.128

If I set my Pihole to have A record of deb12-docker2.local.domain.com (not forwarded), it will work. Is there a way to tell Linux to do another lookup for CNAME record that will need to be forwarded?

Yes, this is unusual / your description seems improbable. Also unusual is a current version of debian which defaults to an external nameserver without customization (which you have not mentioned). Try testing with wireshark/tcpdump


Is your DNS server set up to offer recursion? 2. If so does it know how to get to 192.168.1.1? If not does your client know how to get there?


@symcbean: I may not follow you about the DNS server customization. The DNS server 172.16.100.4 here (Pihole DNS) is supplied by DHCP server. I did a tcpdump and confirmed that nc.domain.com is resolved to CNAME lb2.local.domain.com and then to CNAME deb12-docker2.local.domain.com. It stops there, but never do any further request to resolve deb12-docker2.local.domain.com to an actual IP 172.16.100.128 like macOS client did

@ChrisDavies: My DNS server 172.16.100.4 is setup with a forward zone local.domain.com to 192.168.1.1, so I think it doesn't matter if the client can reach 192.168.1.1 or not as long as it can reach the DNS server 172.16.100.4. To answer your question, yes both Linux and macOS client can reach 192.168.1.1. It just after resolving nc.domain.com to a CNAME record deb12-docker2.local.domain.com the Linux client stops there. With macOS client, it will do another request to resolve deb12-docker2.local.domain.com and get A record 172.16.100.128

It matters very much whether or not the client can teach the second server, depending on how you've got the first one configured. That's why I asked the questions I asked


Is it expected behavior for Linux to NOT do subsequent DNS requests to resolve to an IP?

Yes, it is expected behavior. The the glibc nss_dns module is a stub resolver – it doesn't do any iterative queries; it expects a full answer from the server – and its source code even explicitly calls out this situation:
  if (haveanswer)
    {
      *h_errnop = NETDB_SUCCESS;
      return NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
  else
    {
      /* Special case here: if the resolver sent a result but it only
     contains a CNAME while we are looking for a T_A or T_AAAA
     record, we fail with NOTFOUND.  */
      *h_errnop = HOST_NOT_FOUND;
      return NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND;
    }

In other words, it is literally the job of your specified DNS server to chase CNAMEs and provide the answer to the query it was given. If it's able to resolve the CNAME when asked but doesn't do so the first time, it's not doing the job correctly.

Is there a way to tell Linux to do another lookup for CNAME record that will need to be forwarded?

Set up a local DNS proxy. For example, the systemd-resolved service will make additional queries (to the same server) to follow CNAMEs. Dnsmasq and Unbound might do so as well.

Thank you for your detailed answer. It fits with what I found in Pihole in Pihole documentation (DNS server). It will just return the CNAME unless it is authoritative for the corresponding A record.

...isn't Pihole supposed to be a resolver?
